# How to open a Dialogue Box On Page Load

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am trying to open a Dialogue Box On page load of jquery Mobile screen .Right now i am able to open Dialogue Box on button Click .I want the Dialogue box to get pop up automatically on page load but not able to do it.
Here is the HTML..

```
 <body onload="onLoad()">

 <p style="display: none>You have entered: <span id="dialogoutput"></span></p>

 <a href="#" id="dialoglink" data-role="button" style="display: none>Open Dialog</a>

 <!-- Contacts list page -->
 <div data-role="page" id="cont_list_page" data-theme="a">        
 <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
 </div>
 </div>
 </body>
```

and Here is my jquery ..

```
function onLoad() { 
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
$("#searchby_chooser_ok_button").bind ("click", searchByCriteria); 

if (typeof Contact === "undefined") {
    getElement("contacts_list").innerHTML = "<p>The Cordova Contacts API is inaccessible</p>";
}
}
```

Please help me to pop up the Dialogue on Page Load not on button click event automatically.
Thanks

Comment: $(document).ready(function() { ..dialog open code here..});

Comment: which jQM version are you using?

Comment: @Omar I am using 1.2.0

Comment: It's outdated and no longer maintained, upgrade to 1.4.5. You want to show the dialog on page load before being shown or when it's shown?

Comment: First update your jQM ver at least 1.4.4

Comment: @Ved Ok I will update it to `1.4.4`

Comment: @Ved I have updated to version 1.4.4

Comment: @Omar I have updated to version 1.4.4

Comment: Fwiw, the answers below use Simpledialog - there is also this little project, which does auto-open on load: http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-Windows/doc/4-0-alertbox/

Answer (score 1):

Try using `$(document).ready(function(){})`

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $("#simplestring").simpledialog({
    'mode' : 'string',
    'prompt' : 'Please Enter Your Mobile No.',
    'buttons' : {
      'OK': {
        click: function () {
          $('#dialogoutput').text($('#dialoglink').attr('data-string'));

          //get the Value Entered 
          //Create a Sqlite Database and table 
          //Insert it there 

        }
      },
      'Cancel': {
        click: function () { },
        icon: "delete",
        theme: "c"
      }
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: How to make the visiblity again because i HTML i have set to to none;?

Comment: You can put the code related to Dialog in a function and can call that function both in document.ready and on click event listener

Comment: Its not working in the Mobile ..Let me update my post once again?

Comment: Please see my updated post ..I have shared code..Where i can put your code so that i can see the dialogue box on page load

Comment: Hi am posting a new answer down. Please look at it

Answer (score 0):

You can fire the click in your jquery code as

```
$('#simplestring').click();
```

Write this statement on page load. It will fire click from inside your code and as the click handler does, it will open the dialog :)

Answer (score 0):

```
function onLoad() 
{ 
  openDialogBox();  
  document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
  $("#searchby_chooser_ok_button").bind ("click", searchByCriteria); 

 if (typeof Contact === "undefined") {
    getElement("contacts_list").innerHTML = "<p>The Cordova Contacts API is  inaccessible</p>";
 }
}

function openDialogBox()
{ 
  $("#simplestring").simpledialog({
    'mode' : 'string',
    'prompt' : 'Please Enter Your Mobile No.',
    'buttons' : {
    'OK': {
       click: function () {
         $('#dialogoutput').text($('#dialoglink').attr('data-string'));
       }
     },
     'Cancel': {
       click: function () { },
       icon: "delete",
       theme: "c"
      }
     }
   })
 }
```

Comment: I tried but getting some problem in this ..Instead of this dialogue box to get open on page load i am getting some other dialogue box